# Using ODBC driver without admin privileges

Tags: c++, qt, ms-access, windows-7, odbc

I'm using QODBC driver to access old mdb database (Access 97) like this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName(QString("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%1").arg(dbPath));
```

It works well.

However, Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) is not installed on the targeted system and I cannot have admin privileges to install it.

Things I have tried (that didn't work):

- Extract the driver's dll and modify the connection string to: Driver=PATH/TO/ACEODBC.DLL.
- Create a **USER** ODBC by modifying the registry
- Using native windows OLE/DAE but it's such a pain

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: If the driver isn't there, and the user is not granted rights to install it, you are - of course - hosed.

Comment: @Gustav can't I bring the driver's dll myself and tell the system to look up in my install dir ?

Comment: I doubt it, because Access is not looking up the driver file but the _name_ of the installed driver: `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`.